# How to search for string including digits by grep command

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I have strings in a file in below format:

fixedstring_1
 fixedstring_23
 fixedstring_456
 ...
 fixedstring_[1 to n digits]

I tried with grep -E "fixedstring_[.....n times]" filepath in terminal. But, failed.

I want commands to get the count (-c) and list the lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, given the following file...

```
fixedstring_1
bar
fixedstring_456
foo
fixedstring_45622
fixedstring_
fixedstring
```

You want to match (and get the count of) only these lines:

```
fixedstring_1
fixedstring_456
fixedstring_45622
```

This should work:

```
grep -Ec 'fixedstring_[[:digit:]]+' filename
```

The `[[:digit:]]+` part matches 1 or more digits. More on grep regexes here: http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/grep/manual/grep.html#Regular-Expressions

**EDIT:**

If you want to match strings with only a certain number of digit's you'll have to get a little more clever:

```
grep -E 'fixedstring_[[:digit:]]{MIN,MAX}([^[:digit:]]|$)' filename
```

Replace the `MIN` with the minimum number of digits you want to match, and `MAX` with the max.

Comment: Hi, Thanks you for your prompt reply. If I want to grep for fixedstring_4[1..n digits], what is the command.

Comment: try `grep -E 'fixedstring_4[[:digit:]]{1,N}([^[:digit:]]|$)' filename`. That will grep for strings in `filename` that look like `fixedstring_4` followed by 1 to N digits. So if N is 8 do this: `grep -E 'fixedstring_4[[:digit:]]{1,8}([^[:digit:]]|$)' filename`

Comment: Hi, I want to fetch sub string from output of this grep (string with digits). And, also I need to find duplicates from second output(substrings). I have created another question. ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669847/how-to-get-a-sub-string-from-line-which-is-output-of-other-grep-command