# how to get a sub string from line which is output of other grep command

Tags: linux, unix, vim, grep

I have file with data in multiple lines. I can find the lines by using grep command. I need to get the some portion of string from output of above grep command. And, also need to find any duplicates there.

Thanks.

Comment: if you want to print some portion then use `-o` flag.

Comment: This is very vague. Please include example input, and the expected output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a combination of `grep` and `cut` like:

```
grep PATTERN FILENAME | cut -b x-z
```

where `grep` searches for your `PATTERN` in `FILENAME` and `cut` shows the output from byte `x` to `z` (these should be numbers).

Or you might use a single command:

```
awk '/PATTERN/ { print substr($0,FROM,LENGTH) }' FILENAME
```

in this version you need to replace `FROM` with the byte where the desired output starts and `LENGTH` with ... well you might guess it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many Unix tools for string searching and manipulation, and the chain of `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, up to `perl` provides a (mostly compatible) progression in capabilities. So, you can start out with `grep`, and when that doesn't suit you, "upgrade" to `sed`, and so on. (The reason that the most powerful one hasn't fully driven out the weaker ones is the same like you don't use a big power drill just to put a small nail into a drywall.)

The best solution to your problem depends on the *some portion of string* details. If this is delimited by some character, or at fixed positions, `cut` can do that. To delete unwanted pattern matches, `sed` is the one. With the latter, you can `grep` and delete in one invocation, but it's simpler (and only a bit less efficient) to combine them via *piping*:

```
$ grep PATTERN file | sed 's/unwanted stuff//'
```